# Define a procedure that finds the index of the second instance of a string in a a larger string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am new to python, may i know

Define a procedure that finds the index of the second instance of a string in a larger string.

```
def find_second(findin, whattofind):
      return 

find_second('dance, dance, dance everyday', 'dance')
find_second('learning about data, surprisingly, requires a lot of data','data')
```

Comment: Do you want to know if it is there or where it is as well (if it's there)?

Answer (score 1):

Second index can be found by searching after the first index

You can use `index()` or `find()` for strings.

```
def find_second(findin, whattofind):
    return findin.index(whattofind,findin.index(whattofind)+1)

find_second('dance, dance, dance everyday', 'dance')
find_second('learning about data, surprisingly, requires a lot of data','data')
#output
7
53
```

Or with `find()`

```
def find_second(findin, whattofind):
    return findin.find(whattofind,findin.find(whattofind)+1)

print(find_second('dance, dance, dance everyday', 'dance'))
print(find_second('learning about data, surprisingly, requires a lot of data','data'))
#output
7
53
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`find()`](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-string-methods/python-string-find/) method of strings to know the position of a string inside another string. Since it allows you to specify where to start searching, you can ignore the first occurrence.

Check the following example:

```py
def find_second(haystack, needle):
    first = haystack.find(needle)

    second = haystack.find(needle, first + 1) # We add 1 to skip the first occurrence

    return second
```

This function returns the starting index of the second occurrence of the string `needle` found in `haystack`.